# Javascript - returning objects based on multiple properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, filtering

I need to create a function that takes in an array of `Object`s and returns the objects that match a specific set of criteria.  What I have so far is fairly simple: (pseudocode)

```
// input:  conditions: { prop1: "x", prop2: "z"}
//         source: [{ prop1: "x", prop2: "y"}, { prop1: "x", prop2: "z"}];
// output: array of objects with the same properties & values
// ex:
// getObjects({ prop1: "x", prop2: "z"}, [{ prop1: "x", prop2: "y"}, { prop1: "x", prop2: "z"}]);
// returns: [{ prop1: "x", prop2: "z"}]

//....
var results = [];
for (var prop in obj) {
    var match = false;
    for (var cond in conditions) {
        if (cond === prop && conditions[cond] == obj[prop]) {
            match = true;
        }
    }
    if (match) {
        results.push(row);
    }
}
return results;
```

where `conditions` is an object that represents one or more properties that the matching object must possess.

The problem is that this is somehow returning duplicate objects, which obviously can't happen.  I know there is a standard way to accomplish this (probably a programming 101 kind of thing), but my Google-foo is failing me.

NOTE:  I can't use `Array.prototype.filter` here because of the context.  I'm running through a set or rows in a table and only want to return the ones that match certain criteria.

Basically the idea is "return the objects that are *similar to* the input object.

Comment: Are you sure the resulting duplicate objects are due to this script and not from the query producing the rows from the source table?

Comment: @DevlshOne: There are not queries involved.  The table in question is a `<table>` manually constructed in markup.  Though what I'm essentially doing is a query.

Comment: Could you provide more detail on the criteria and a sample of table rows?

Comment: @DevlshOne: Check my updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close from the solution.
If several properties match, you will add the 'row' for each match.
Just add it once per row, after loop on condition **and** loop on prop ended.
It is a matter of curly brace position :

```
var results = [];
for (var i =0; i<source.length; i++) {
    var row = source[i];
    var match = true;  
    var samePropCount = 0;
    for (var prop in row) {
        for (var cond in conditions) {
            if (cond === prop ) {
                samePropCount++;
                if (conditions[cond] != row[prop]) {
                   match = false;
                }
            }
        }  
    } 
    if (!samePropCount) match=false;
    if (match) {
        results.push(row);
    }
}
return results;
```

Comment: The logic of this is flawed. Supposed your object is `{a:1, b:2, c:3}` and conditions is `{a:1, c:4}`. As soon as a match is found in `{a:1}`, match will be set to true. The item will incorrectly be added to results because there is no match for `c`

Comment: from the pseudocode provided, it looks like all properties must match. object `{ prop1: "x", prop2: "y"}` is not in the results when the condition is `{ prop1: "x", prop2: "z"}`

Comment: @BrianGlaz you are right, i did not read carefully enough. Now it might be good.

Comment: @GameAlchemist: This works great!  I knew I was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

With [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#filter):

```
var evens = _.filter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(num){ return num % 2 == 0; });
=> [2, 4, 6]
```

do you want to implement the function?

Comment: Basically, yes.  But I need it to be able to take in an object that represents what conditions are to be met.

Comment: you can pass an array of objects to  filter